# How to get a maximum of parameters to determine a browser issue?

Tags: javascript, html, http, cross-browser, compatibility

I am working on a new website and  I need to develop something to help user manage technical browsers issues. There are many parameters (8) I need to check and I am wondering if some of those could be checked in-browser, mainly through javascript.

Here's the list of parameters I need to look about :

- is **SSL** activated?
- is **MSXML** activated? (for *ajax* and based on browser security level according to the notes I have)
- what **update version of IE6** is used? (if the user has IE6, he needs at least IE6 SP2)
- what **HTTP version** is used? (1.1 is required)

(The 4 others (browser name, browser version, javascript and cookies) can be tested with javascript)

So, which of those parameters can be tested in the browser, and how?

If one of the parameters I stated is useless, feel free to point it too (and why!)

Comment: The HTTP version parameter is useless - there is no browser any more that uses 1.0

Comment: It is possible to deactivate HTTP1.1 in IE. Dumb but possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never know the HTTP version used by client ever being an issue.

Your description of 'is SSL activated' is probably a server side check, most SSL certificates are compatible with 99.9%+ of browsers so it's a redundant metric.

The solution for the user being on IE6 is always upgrade your browser.

The only concern I would check for is IE6, maybe even IE7 and have a notification letting them know to upgrade their browser.  The other checks are overkill unless you are developing something extremely niche.  Browser version can be detected *reasonablly* reliably with USER_AGENT

Comment: The HTTP version used to be an issue, but that time has long gone.

Comment: I've been told some user had http1.1 deactivated in their IE settings, hence why it is there. And since many users are from corporations, we can tell them to upgrade, but their IT department may deny it :)